# How to solve this issue in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

In this web-application, from the "mainpage", there is a "support" icon on the navigation bar, by which user may click it to have the "support" page opened also. As if there are 2 tabs in the browser, one is of mainpage, one is of support page.

In my checking case, I want to verify that if user is clicking this icon, it does reach the "support" page.  And here is my code in general:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://mainpage.xyz.com"
driver.get(url)

by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
support = "..."
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by, support))).click()
assert "support" in driver.current_url
```

But, somehow, during the assertion, what I have seen is the value of driver.current_url is still of the "mainpage.xyz.com".  Any idea to fix such issue ?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: the driver will not switch the window/tab unless you tell it to.  Use "numberOfWindowsToBe" expected condition ( https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfWindowsToBe-int- ) and then switch the driver to the tab/window handle that is not the current one.

Answer (score 0):

I have just googled and have found a solution as this :

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://mainpage.xyz.com"
driver.get(url)

by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    support = "..."
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by,support))).click()

# this call switch from the main tab to the support tab. 
# and I can have the url asserted after that.      
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
assert "support" in driver.current_url

# this call switch back from support tab to mainpage tab.  
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```